# How to calculate the average of different groups in a dataset using R

Tags: r

I have a dataset in R that I would like to find the average of a given variable for each year in the dataset (here, from 1871-2019). Not every year has the same number of entries, and so I have encountered two problems: first, how to find the average of the variable for each year, and second, how to add the column of averages to the dataset. I am unsure how to approach the first problem, but I attempted a version of the second problem by simply finding the sum of each group and then trying to add those values to the dataset for each entry of a given year with the code `teams$SBtotal <- tapply(teams$SB, teams$yearID, FUN=sum)`. That code resulted in an error that notes `replacement has 149 rows, data has 2925`. I know that this can be done less quickly in Excel, but I'm hoping to be able to use R to solve this problem.

Comment: Please show a small reproduicble example with `dput` as this should work `tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, FUN = sum)#setosa versicolor  virginica 
     250.3      296.8      329.4`

Comment: If you are summarizing the data with `tapply` you cannot assing back to the same df. Try `ave()` instead, its return value *has the same length* as the input.

Answer (score 0):

The `tapply` should work

```
data(iris)
tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, FUN = sum)
```